# Embed segue are not available on ios 5.1

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an app on the app store which Requires iOS 6.0 or later. I just loaded my project with Xcode 5, and I saw the error message Class Unavailable Embed segues are not available on iOS 5.1 and prior. I have verified IOS Deployment target is 6.0 and IOS Deployment target is 6.0. Prior to xcode 5 I had no issues any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have met the same problem today. Switched Deployment target to 7.0, cleaned&built the project (with error), and then switched back to 6.1, cleaned again. Now project builds.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. I thought this was sdk version or deployment target. It wasn't there is additional setting in the storyboard properties tab of interface builder. I changed "Build for" to ios 6.0 and later. Issue gone.